# Oracle case statement with opposing expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table for analysis (see image).

I need orders where the rank 1 is Fulfilled, and the order has passed through which (Project or Unit) approval status (apparently some orders can skip approvals).

Also, Need to create this in a single select statement.

Could you please help me build a Oracle SQL for this. I tried using various combinations of Case statement, but unable to pull a flag with opposing conditions. Thanks!

| order region | order number | order status | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 1234 | Fulfilled | 1 |
| New York | 1234 | shippped | 2 |
| New York | 1234 | Approved - Unit Level | 3 |
| New York | 1234 | Queued - Unit Level | 4 |
| New York | 1234 | Approved - Project Level | 5 |
| New York | 1234 | Queued - Project Level | 6 |
| New York | 1234 | Submitted | 7 |

Tried SQL:

```
SELECT ORDER_REGION, 
CASE WHEN RANK=1 AND ORDER_STATUS = 'Fulfilled' then
 case when rank>1 and order_status not like '%Queued - Project level%' then 'N' else 'Y' end end  is_it_approved_at_project
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_Region;
```

Desired Output :

| Order Number | Is It approved at Project | Is It approved at Project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Y | Y |
| 5678 | N | Y |
| 9100 | Y | N |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT   order_number,
         CASE
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status = 'Approved - Unit Level' THEN 1 END) = 0
         THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS is_approved_unit,
         CASE
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN order_status = 'Approved - Project Level' THEN 1 END) = 0
         THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS is_approved_project
FROM     orders
GROUP BY order_number
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN rank = 1 AND order_status = 'Fulfilled' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders ( order_region, order_number, order_status, rank ) AS
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Fulfilled',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'shippped', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Approved - Unit Level',    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Queued - Unit Level',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Approved - Project Level', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Queued - Project Level',   6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'New York',  1234,   'Submitted',    7 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER_NUMBER | IS_APPROVED_UNIT | IS_APPROVED_PROJECT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Y | Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IbI3sHdf)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like using `exists` could help to solve this problem:

```
select order_region
from orders as ordersFulfilled
where ordersFulfilled.rank = 1
and ordersFulfilled.order_status = 'Fulfilled'
and exists (
    select 1
    from orders as ordersQueued
    where ordersFulfilled.order_number = ordersQueued.order_number
    and ordersFulfilled.rank > 1
    and ordersFulfilled.order_status not like 'Queued - Project level%'
);
```

Note that this query will only return rows that fulfill the condition. If you need orders that do not fulfill the condition, you can just use `not exists` instead of `exists`.

Also you should be aware that string comparison in queries can be quite "expensive", especially when using wildcards. That's why I removed the wildcard at the beginning of the array, because this will work more like "starts with" instead of "contains". However, this will only be effective when the column `order_status` is indexed. A better approach would be using numbers instead of strings for status columns (and of course add an index on this column).